# overloading the operator ->

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

I was looking at overloading the `->` operator. I came up with the following simple example:

```
struct foo
{
    int p = 12;
};

struct A
{    
    foo* f;
    A()
    {
        this->f = new foo();
    }
    foo* operator-> ()
    {
        return f;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << a->p; //output 12
}
```

Although this example works, yet I am hoping if someone could tell me why it works.
I was thinking that it should work like this

```
std::cout << a->->p; //The first arrow returns the pointer 
                     //the second arrow dereferences it
```

but here it seems like a single arrow not only returns the pointer but it also dereferences it. Is this a special case in C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is by-design, [`operator->`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_member_access_operators) will be called recursively on the return value; then we can use such class (so-called smart pointers) in the same way as raw pointers.

> If a user-defined `operator->` is provided, the `operator->` is called again on the value that it returns, recursively, until an `operator->` is reached that returns a plain pointer. After that, built-in semantics are applied to that pointer.

Comment: I'm not sure this explains why `operator->` can't return a reference. Smart pointers would just return references instead of pointers. (In fact, it's not clear to me why `operator->` cannot be implicitly implemented in terms of unary `operator*`.)